# Finding the linear transformation $\Bbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^4$ given the kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$$\operatorname{Ker}(T) = [(1,0,2,4),(-2,1,1,0),(-1,1,3,4)]$$

My attempt:

$T(1,0,2,4) = 0, T(-2,1,1,0) = 0, T(-1,1,3,4) = 0.$

$$ \displaylines{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
}$$
Scaling the matrix:
$$ \displaylines{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 5 & 8 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
}$$

$a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = -8$, $a_3 = 0$, $a_4 = 1$.

The linear transformation would be:

$T(x,y,w,z) = (-4x-8y+z,-4x-8y+z,-4x-8y+z,-4x-8y+z)$?
$$ \displaylines{\\}$$
**Updating after the tips informed:**
$$ \displaylines{T(1,0,2,4) = (0,0,0,0), \\
T(-2,1,1,0) = (0,0,0,0) \\
T(1,0,0,0) = (1,0,0,0) \\
T(0,1,0,0) = (0,1,0,0) \\
}$$
$(x,y,z,w) = \alpha_1 (1,0,2,4) +  \alpha_2 (-2,1,1,0) + \alpha_3 (1,0,0,0)  +\alpha_4 (0,1,0,0)$

$$ \displaylines{ \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 - 2\alpha_2 + \alpha_3 = x \\
\alpha_2 + \alpha_4 = y\\
2\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 = z\\
4\alpha_1 = w
\end{bmatrix}
}$$

$$\alpha_1 = \frac{w}{4}; \alpha_2 = z - \frac{2w}{4}; \alpha_3 = x - \frac{5w}{4}+2z; \alpha_4 = y-z + \frac{2w}{4}$$
$$ \displaylines{\\}$$
$$(x,y,z,w) = \frac{w}{4}(1,0,2,4) + z - \frac{2w}{4}(-2,1,1,0) + x - \frac{5w}{4}+2z(1,0,0,0) + y-z + \frac{2w}{4} (0,1,0,0)$$

$$T(x,y,z,w) = \frac{w}{4}T(1,0,2,4) + z - \frac{2w}{4}T(-2,1,1,0) + x - \frac{5w}{4}+2zT(1,0,0,0) + y-z + \frac{2w}{4}T(0,1,0,0)$$

I got stuck in this part.

Comment: You solution must be incorrect, because every element in the image is of the form $(u,u,u,u)$, which means the Image has dimension $1$. But the Kernel has dimension $2$, as you have shown, so the dimension of the image must be $2$ by the rank-nullity theorem

Comment: You already proved that it's enough to consider  $(1,0,2,4)$ and $(-2,1,1,0)$ for the kernel. So, you only need to find two extra l.i vectors, and then define T on those vectors to be anything (but not 0).

Comment: @hugod Do I need to use canonical basis (1,0,0,0) and (0,1,0,0) and equal to (x, y, w, z) and then check?

Comment: No, consider a basis of the form $\{(1,0,2,4),(-2,1,1,0),v_3,v_4\}$  because you already know the value of T at the first 2 vectors.

Comment: @Ed_Zepp as the set of vectors $\{(1,0,2,4),  (−2,1,1,0) ,(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0) \}$ is linearly independent of size 4,  you can use it as a basis

Comment: You can find **a** map with that kernel, but not **the** map with that kernel, because there are many more than $1.$